# RMarkdown: Getting Summation to appear larger

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I am trying to get the Summation to appear bigger in RMarkdown and I use this in OverLeaf and it produce the right result :

```
$\cos x = \mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ix)^2n}{(2n)!}$
```

But when I put it in RMarkdown and run Knit  to PDF it gave me the following result:

```
cosx=\mathlarger\mathlarger∑∞n=0(ix)2n(2n)!
```

Here is the image of what I want it to look like:
    [image: Large Summation]

Comment: Did you make sure you had the relsize package loaded? add `header-includes: \usepackage{relsize}` to your yaml front matter for this

Comment: Use $\cos x = \displaystyle ...$.